# Function imfindcircles Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, uint8t

I'm using the function imfindcircles on image but occurs an error that says that function or method 'imfindcircles' for input arguments of type 'uint8'. I'm using this tutorial of [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detect-and-measure-circular-objects-in-an-image.html). My code:

```
rgb = imread('circles.png');
figure
imshow(rgb)
gray_image = rgb2gray(rgb);
imshow(gray_image);
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(I,[40 45]);
centersStrong5 = centers(1:5,:);
radiiStrong5 = radii(1:5);
metricStrong5 = metric(1:5);
```

This is the error: ??? Undefined function or method 'imfindcircles' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `imfindcircles.m` in your current working directory?

Comment: No. This is function of Matlab

Comment: I understand that MATLAB has a function called `imfindcircles`. What I'm asking is if you've overshadowed that implementation with your own function or variable name. Because that's the only way I can think of right now that that error makes sense.

Comment: I google it and find that this function is implementend  on Image Processing toolbox. How do I install this toolbox?

Comment: If you don't already have a license, you buy one from Mathworks. http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because I was not defined. Replace I with gray_image and it'll work.

```
 [centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(gray_image,[40 45]);
```

You don't need any special toolbox or license for this function.